# data.table roll "nearest" left join for single best match (rest to NA)

Tags: r, data.table, match, left-join

I have two data.tables with different number of rows. I would like to left join by matching on a single column so that first dt `dt1` keeps all rows. Only best nearest values from second `dt2` should be joined.

**Minimal data:**

```r
library(data.table)

set.seed(42)

timestamp <- sort(rnorm(10, mean = 1, sd = 1))

dt1 <- data.table(
  id = letters[1:10],
  timestamp = timestamp,
  timestamp1 = timestamp,
  other1 = 1:10,
  other2 = 11:20
)

dt2 <- data.table(
  timestamp = timestamp[c(3, 5, 8)] + 0.1,
  timestamp2 = timestamp[c(3, 5, 8)] + 0.1,
  other3 = c("x", "y", "z"),
  other4 = c(333, 444, 555)
)
```

**What I tried:**

```r
dt2[dt1, roll = "nearest", on = "timestamp"]
#>     timestamp timestamp2 other3 other4 id timestamp1 other1 other2
#>  1: 0.4353018   1.005341      x    333  a  0.4353018      1     11
#>  2: 0.8938755   1.005341      x    333  b  0.8938755      2     12
#>  3: 0.9053410   1.005341      x    333  c  0.9053410      3     13
#>  4: 0.9372859   1.005341      x    333  d  0.9372859      4     14
#>  5: 1.3631284   1.463128      y    444  e  1.3631284      5     15
#>  6: 1.4042683   1.463128      y    444  f  1.4042683      6     16
#>  7: 1.6328626   1.463128      y    444  g  1.6328626      7     17
#>  8: 2.3709584   2.470958      z    555  h  2.3709584      8     18
#>  9: 2.5115220   2.470958      z    555  i  2.5115220      9     19
#> 10: 3.0184237   2.470958      z    555  j  3.0184237     10     20
```

I am failing to understand how `roll="nearest"` works. I see that it indeed matches the nearest values, but it does it with all of them. I would like to merge only those 3 rows from `dt2` that have the absolute nearest values.

Using joins based on tolerance (max_dist) would also give more than three matches, but in this case I found the value of `max_dist` that gives the *best nearest* for this tiny example data.

**Desired output:**

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzyjoin::difference_left_join(as.data.frame(dt1), as.data.frame(dt2), by = "timestamp", max_dist = 0.09)
#>    id timestamp.x timestamp1 other1 other2 timestamp.y timestamp2 other3 other4
#> 1   a   0.4353018  0.4353018      1     11          NA         NA   <NA>     NA
#> 2   b   0.8938755  0.8938755      2     12          NA         NA   <NA>     NA
#> 3   c   0.9053410  0.9053410      3     13          NA         NA   <NA>     NA
#> 4   d   0.9372859  0.9372859      4     14    1.005341   1.005341      x    333
#> 5   e   1.3631284  1.3631284      5     15          NA         NA   <NA>     NA
#> 6   f   1.4042683  1.4042683      6     16    1.463128   1.463128      y    444
#> 7   g   1.6328626  1.6328626      7     17          NA         NA   <NA>     NA
#> 8   h   2.3709584  2.3709584      8     18          NA         NA   <NA>     NA
#> 9   i   2.5115220  2.5115220      9     19    2.470958   2.470958      z    555
#> 10  j   3.0184237  3.0184237     10     20          NA         NA   <NA>     NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement a rolling join "without replacement" (a row in either source table should map to 0 or 1 rows in the result)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71992098/how-to-implement-a-rolling-join-without-replacement-a-row-in-either-source-ta)

Comment: There is no requirement to comment on downvotes, score voting is anonymous, and there is never a reason to be rude. [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: There is no question here. PS Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask]

Comment: The question is clear and well formatted -- not sure where that criticism is coming from. However, "the absolute nearest value" is ~0.04 not 0.1 here. Try `dt2[dt1, roll = "nearest", on = "timestamp", min(abs(x.timestamp - i.timestamp))]` or look at row 9 in the "what I tried" block. You can take this min value and use it to check whether you want to set a row to NA instead of taking the rowwise nearest (which is what data.table provides).

Comment: @Frank Again: There is no question in the post (title or body). Observations, an attempt & wants are reported. Also see my last comment; it's not clear whether they are trying to ask about their misconceptions & bad code or their overall goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a proper left update join and assign the desired variables from `dt2` explicitely

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(42)

timestamp <- sort(rnorm(10, mean = 1, sd = 1))

dt1 <- data.table(
  id = letters[1:10],
  timestamp = timestamp,
  timestamp1 = timestamp,
  other1 = 1:10,
  other2 = 11:20
)

dt2 <- data.table(
  timestamp = timestamp[c(3, 5, 8)] + 0.1,
  timestamp2 = timestamp[c(3, 5, 8)] + 0.1,
  other3 = c("x", "y", "z"),
  other4 = c(333, 444, 555)
)

# left join: leading table on the left
dt1[dt2,
    roll = "nearest",
    on = "timestamp", 
    # assign desired values explicitely
    `:=`(other3 = i.other3,
         other4 = i.other4)]
dt1[]
#>     id timestamp timestamp1 other1 other2 other3 other4
#>  1:  a 0.4353018  0.4353018      1     11   <NA>     NA
#>  2:  b 0.8938755  0.8938755      2     12   <NA>     NA
#>  3:  c 0.9053410  0.9053410      3     13   <NA>     NA
#>  4:  d 0.9372859  0.9372859      4     14      x    333
#>  5:  e 1.3631284  1.3631284      5     15   <NA>     NA
#>  6:  f 1.4042683  1.4042683      6     16      y    444
#>  7:  g 1.6328626  1.6328626      7     17   <NA>     NA
#>  8:  h 2.3709584  2.3709584      8     18   <NA>     NA
#>  9:  i 2.5115220  2.5115220      9     19      z    555
#> 10:  j 3.0184237  3.0184237     10     20   <NA>     NA
```